# Laracast #15.Easy Authentication video in Laravel 5 Fundamentals series

Tags: php, laravel-5

Now when i register a user i get redirected to /home page, but when i do like Jeff and "logout" the user and get redirected back to /home (which isn't there yet), all of that is fine, but then when i want to go to /auth/register, i get redirected back to /home instantly, i tried a couple of things, and then i tried deleting the user manually using tinker, only then i can go to /auth/register, and then the same problem again, i get stuck at the /home page, i also changed the $redirectTo = '/articles'; , when i forwarded a bit in the video, i see that Jeff does this (\Auth::user();) to find the currently logged in user, i found that whenever i do this i always find the user that i registered is still logged in, unless i delete the user i created, the user is always logged in, the logout method isn't working, any ideas?

My AuthController:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */
    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    protected $redirectTo = '/articles';

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }
    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        ]);
    }
    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'username' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

RedirectUsers.php:

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

trait RedirectsUsers
{
    /**
     * Get the post register / login redirect path.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function redirectPath()
    {
        if (property_exists($this, 'redirectPath')) {
            return $this->redirectPath;
        }

        return property_exists($this, 'redirectTo') ? $this->redirectTo : '/article';
    }
}
```

AuthenticatesUsers.php:

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;

trait AuthenticatesUsers
{
    use RedirectsUsers;

    /**
     * Show the application login form.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function getLogin()
    {
        if (view()->exists('auth.authenticate')) {
            return view('auth.authenticate');
        }

        return view('auth.login');
    }

    /**
     * Handle a login request to the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function postLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            $this->loginUsername() => 'required', 'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
        // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
        // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
        $throttles = $this->isUsingThrottlesLoginsTrait();

        if ($throttles && $this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
            return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
        }

        $credentials = $this->getCredentials($request);

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
            return $this->handleUserWasAuthenticated($request, $throttles);
        }

        // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
        // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
        // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
        if ($throttles) {
            $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
        }

        return redirect($this->loginPath())
            ->withInput($request->only($this->loginUsername(), 'remember'))
            ->withErrors([
                $this->loginUsername() => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
            ]);
    }

    /**
     * Send the response after the user was authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  bool  $throttles
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    protected function handleUserWasAuthenticated(Request $request, $throttles)
    {
        if ($throttles) {
            $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);
        }

        if (method_exists($this, 'authenticated')) {
            return $this->authenticated($request, Auth::user());
        }

        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }

    /**
     * Get the needed authorization credentials from the request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->only($this->loginUsername(), 'password');
    }

    /**
     * Get the failed login message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getFailedLoginMessage()
    {
        return Lang::has('auth.failed')
                ? Lang::get('auth.failed')
                : 'These credentials do not match our records.';
    }

    /**
     * Log the user out of the application.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function getLogout()
    {
        Auth::logout();

        return redirect(property_exists($this, 'redirectAfterLogout') ? $this->redirectAfterLogout : '/');
    }

    /**
     * Get the path to the login route.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function loginPath()
    {
        return property_exists($this, 'loginPath') ? $this->loginPath : '/auth/login';
    }

    /**
     * Get the login username to be used by the controller.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function loginUsername()
    {
        return property_exists($this, 'username') ? $this->username : 'email';
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function isUsingThrottlesLoginsTrait()
    {
        return in_array(
            ThrottlesLogins::class, class_uses_recursive(get_class($this))
        );
    }
}
```

routes.php:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});



Route::get('about', 'PagesController@about');
Route::get('contact', 'PagesController@contact');

Route::resource('articles', 'ArticlesController');

Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change 
`$this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);`
to
`$this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);`
in your AuthController